# Which one is best react native FlatList or Flipkart recyclerlistview?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a booking app using react native, where I have to show multiple lists. Can someone tell me which one is best to use, native FlatList or Flipkart recyclerlistview?

React Native FlatList:: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Flipkart recyclerlistview :: https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

Comment: I am not familiar with recyclerlistview, but Flatlist will be my choice. good support for paging and refreshcontroll.

Comment: hey there , I am also not use recyclerlistview, but I mostly use Flatlist in my code. so my choice is Flatlist and its also easy to use

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your list complexity and size.

If you need to show large lists (100+ elements) in booking app and want a hassle free smooth experience for users, then go for Flipkart's recyclerlistview.

It has a lot of improvements over a FlatList, but you might struggle with its documentation. It's usage is pretty simple and self-explanatory for an expert though.

If your list elements are not large in numbers, then you can blindly opt for FlatList.